# RAD Studio XE6 não conecta a nenhum banco de dados!

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, delphi, sql-server, delphi-xe6

Programa utilizado: RAD Studio XE6 (32bits).

Problema: Ao criar um novo projeto Desktop ou Mobile, ao tentar configurar a conexão a qualquer banco de dados, seja por FireDAC ou dbExpress, ocorre o seguinte erro:

"DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path."

Qual seria a solução para este problema?

Comment: já tentou buscar pelas dlls de acesso ao banco na pasta de instalação? pode ser que o caminho para elas não está no PATH nem no diretorio do executável

Comment: onde vejo os diretórios no xe6?

Comment: elas vão estar no Lib ou no Bin da sua instalação do delphi. Daí elas devem está na variável de sistema PATH do seu windows ou ser copiada para dentro da pasta bin do seu projeto

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você precisa ir na guia de componentes "FireDAC Links", e colocar o componente no seu projeto, correspondente ao banco que você está tentando usar.
Por exemplo, eu uso o PostgreSQL e coloquei ao lado do componente de conexão o componente TFDPhysPgDriverLink da guia de componentes "FireDAC Links", simples assim.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive um problema parecido ao tentar conectar com uma base de dados do Postgre utilizando FireDAC no Delphi XE6.

A solução foi voltar a versão da DLL "libpq.dll" para 9.2.2.1317.

No Firebird conectada normalmente.